# create new column that telling the values why they are not selected on pandas?

Tags: pandas

**Input**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['JOHN','ALLEN','BOB','NIKI','CHARLIE','CHANG'],
              'Age':[35,42,63,29,47,51],
              'Salary_in_1000':[100,93,78,120,64,115],
             'FT_Team':['STEELERS','SEAHAWKS','FALCONS','FALCONS','PATRIOTS','STEELERS']})


n1=(df['Age']< 60)
n2=(df['Salary_in_1000']>=100) 
n3=(df['FT_Team'].str.startswith('S'))
```

Using these conditions to select, it will return JOHN and CHANG.

**Goal**

I want to create dataframe where data is not selected and a new column which returns which conditions is not expected. For example,

```
* ALLEN: n1, n2
* BOB: n2,n3
* NIKI: n3
* CHANG: n2,n3
```

The new column name is `reason`. The value is the condition variable and the type is string.

**Try**

I have to try each condition and record each variable violates which rules by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a new dataframe then use `.dot` matrix on the boolean values and the column names.

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'n1' : n1, 'n2' : n2, 'n3' : n3})

df['reason'] = s.eq(False).dot(s.columns +',').str.rstrip(',')

print(df)
      Name  Age  Salary_in_1000   FT_Team    reason
0     JOHN   35             100  STEELERS          
1    ALLEN   42              93  SEAHAWKS        n2
2      BOB   63              78   FALCONS  n1,n2,n3
3     NIKI   29             120   FALCONS        n3
4  CHARLIE   47              64  PATRIOTS     n2,n3
5    CHANG   51             115  STEELERS
```

---

Comment: very nice +1, but i think he wants the inverted conditions

Comment: @tdy thank you my friend, easy enough to invert! although one could just write the correct boolean to begin with!

Comment: @Umar.H great, but if  there are more than 10 rules , it's not convenient to create rules dataframe.

Comment: @Jack if you pass the conditions to a list you could create a dictionary i.e `s = pd.DataFrame({ f"n{i}" : data for i,data in enumerate([rules]) })`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for each row and assign the value to the column like this:

```
def get_reason(row):
    n1 = row['Age'] < 60
    n2= row['Salary_in_1000']>=100
    n3= row['FT_Team'].startswith('S')
    
    conditions = {'n1': n1,'n2': n2,'n3': n3}

    #Get the conditions which were violated
    violated = [x for x in conditions if not conditions[x]]
    
    #join to string
    return ",".join(violated)

df['reasons'] = df.apply(get_reason, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Name    Age Salary_in_1000  FT_Team     reasons
JOHN    35  100             STEELERS    
ALLEN   42  93              SEAHAWKS    n2
BOB     63  78              FALCONS     n1,n2,n3
NIKI    29  120             FALCONS     n3
CHARLIE 47  64              PATRIOTS    n2,n3
CHANG   51  115             STEELERS
```