# python string eval string got error in dict

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [33]: def select_func(df):
    ...:     df=df.copy()
    ...:     rules=["df['Age']<60"]
    ...:     s={ f"n{i}" :eval(r) for i,r in enumerate(rules) }
    ...:     return df

In [34]: select_func(df=df1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-4cc0569a2417> in <module>
----> 1 select_func(df=df1)

<ipython-input-33-0613bd096f62> in select_func(df)
      2     df=df.copy()
      3     rules=["df['Age']<60"]
----> 4     s={ f"n{i}" :eval(r) for i,r in enumerate(rules) }
      5     return df
      6

<ipython-input-33-0613bd096f62> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      2     df=df.copy()
      3     rules=["df['Age']<60"]
----> 4     s={ f"n{i}" :eval(r) for i,r in enumerate(rules) }
      5     return df
      6

<string> in <module>

NameError: name 'df' is not defined

df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['JOHN','ALLEN','BOB','NIKI','CHARLIE','CHANG'],
              'Age':[35,42,63,29,47,51],
              'Salary_in_1000':[100,93,78,120,64,115],
             'FT_Team':['STEELERS','SEAHAWKS','FALCONS','FALCONS','PATRIOTS','STEELERS']})
```

It is strange that `eval()` in `dict` got an error. Strangely enough, it works without `dict`.

- Note：`df1` is a must. I do not want to only use `df` as an input variable. `df1` is also necessary for my application.
- My Goal is that creating columns telling why the row is not selected, which refers [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362002/create-new-column-that-telling-the-values-why-they-are-not-selected-on-pandas/67362201#67362201). But I don't want to create n1,n2,…… to refer each condition. Instead, I want to using raw conditions as variable.
- env

  Python 3.7.9 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec  9 2020, 20:36:16) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
  IPython 7.32.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

Comment: Why are you even using `eval` at all?

Comment: @user2357112 it's an example, I delete other conditions. There are more than 15 rules.  I want to use this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/67362201/5576930 , but not using n1, n2……

Comment: You don't need `eval` for that.

Comment: There's nothing in that post about using `eval`. [Read](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly: You likely assigned something to the `df` name at global scope. This code should produce an error.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, I think the problem is that there are many different names like df.

Comment: Don't know why, but it seems to work if you don't use dict comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The minimal example

The minimal example of your problem is:

```
m1=1

def outer_fun(m):
    commands = ["m"]
    s = {i: eval(r) for i, r in enumerate(commands)}

outer_fun(m1)
```

Which gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_53/eval.py", line 7, in <module>
    outer_fun(m1)
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_53/eval.py", line 5, in outer_fun
    s = {i: eval(r) for i, r in enumerate(commands)}
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_53/eval.py", line 5, in <dictcomp>
    s = {i: eval(r) for i, r in enumerate(commands)}
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'm' is not defined
```

### Simplify the dict comprehension operation

The dict comprehension makes the problem complex and conceals the essence, let's get rid of it.

1. According to the [PEP 274](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/), the expression in you question is equivalent to `s = dict([(i, eval(r)) for i, r in enumerate(commands)])`, where the `[(i, eval(r)) for i, r in enumerate(commands)]` causes the problem.
2. I think the [list comprehesion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) used above will use lambda function.You can get rid of the list comprehension, perhpas get something like `s = list(map(lambda i, r: (i, eval(r)), range(len(commands)), commands))` **(EDIT: this is not accurate, see my question [Is list comprehension implemented via map and lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72991388/9758790), they are not the same, but they work in a similar way; Perhaps one can still uses the `lambda` to understand the behavior of list comprehension if doesn't want to refer to python assembly)**. And just applying the lambda function `(lambda i, r: (i, eval(r)))(0, "m")` will result in problems!
3. Using an explict function definition to replace the lambda function that cause the problem. which gives:

```
m1=1

def outer_fun(m):
    commands = ["m"]
    # All of the following lines fails:
    # s = {i: eval(r) for i, r in enumerate(commands)}
    # s = dict([(i, eval(r)) for i, r in enumerate(commands)])
    # s = [(i, eval(r)) for i, r in enumerate(commands)]
    # s = list(map(lambda i, r: (i, eval(r)), range(len(commands)), commands))
    # (lambda i, r: (i, eval(r)))(0, "m")
    def inner_func(i, r):
        return (i, eval(r))

    inner_func(0, "m")
outer_fun(m1)
```

And it is just like:

```
m1=1

def outer_fun(m):
    def inner_func():
        return (0, eval("m"))

    inner_func()
outer_fun(m1)
```

### A most simplified version

A most simplified version will be:

```
m1=1

def outer_fun(m):
    def inner_func():
        eval("m")
    inner_func()
outer_fun(m1)
```

Which give:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_53/eval.py", line 7, in <module>
    outer_fun(m1)
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_53/eval.py", line 6, in outer_fun
    inner_func()
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_53/eval.py", line 5, in inner_func
    eval("m")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'm' is not defined
```

### Why the "most simplified version" raise exception

You can refer to the [doc of eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). If arguments *globals* and *locals* are not passed to the `eval`, the `eval` is executed with the globals and locals in the environment where eval() is called. However, `m` is not the local variable of `inner_func`, nor a global variable(but `m1` is a global variable).

Another thing that may be insteresting is that if you replace the `eval('m')` with `print(m)`, the `inner_func` can print without any problem, this is because `m` is the local variable of the `outer_func` that the `inner_func` can access.

You can check the globals and locals with the function `globals()` and `locals()`:

```
m1=1

def outer_fun(m):
    print("local in outer:")
    print(locals())
    print("global in outer:")
    print(globals())
    def inner_func():
        print("local in inner:")
        print(locals())
        print("global in inner:")
        print(globals())
        eval("m")
    inner_func()
outer_fun(m1)
```

Which gives:

```
local in outer:
{'m': 1}
global in outer:
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f0d85ad0eb0>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': '/tmp/pycharm_project_53/11.py', '__cached__': None, 'm1': 1, 'outer_fun': <function outer_fun at 0x7f0d85ad6280>}
local in inner:
{}
global in inner:
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f0d85ad0eb0>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': '/tmp/pycharm_project_53/11.py', '__cached__': None, 'm1': 1, 'outer_fun': <function outer_fun at 0x7f0d85ad6280>}
```

### How to fix

You should store the globals and locals, and then pass them to the `eval`.

```
m1=1

def outer_fun(m):
    commands = ["m"]
    globs = globals()
    locs = locals()
    s = {i: eval(r, globs, locs) for i, r in enumerate(commands)}
    print(s)
outer_fun(m1)
```

### Futher reading

These questions may be related:

1. [NameError using eval inside dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32763500/9758790)
2. [Python Name Error in dict comprehension when called inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52892171/9758790)
3. [eval fails in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194934/eval-fails-in-list-comprehension)